# Name and solution of puzzle to rotate all arrows to same direction

Tags: puzzle-identification, solvability, lights-out

In this puzzle, when you click an arrow, all arrows immediately next to it (diagonally included), as well as the arrow you clicked itself rotate 90 degrees.  The goal is to get all the of arrows to point in the same direction (say, upwards).

What's the name of, and solution to, this puzzle?  I tried googling "arrow rotation puzzle", but that clearly isn't descriptive enough.

[image]

Comment: I would say it's a variation of the "lights off" game, but I don't know if this particular version with the arrows has a specific name

Comment: Yeah this is "lights out" but with integers modulo 4 instead of modulo 2.

Comment: ...or lights out with two layers, you can only toggle lights on the top layer, and every light on the bottom layer gets toggled when the one above it gets turned off x)

Comment: It is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Clock

Answer (score 0):

I found the game and played around a little to try and find a solution and found something that works pretty consistently.

1. Turn all the corners facing up
2. To turn the top middle and bottom middle, use the corners corresponding to the piece. Turn one corner until the middle matches the opposite corner, then turn the other corner until it matches the first, then to flip them all up, turn the edge piece until it faces up.
3. Repeat on the bottom
4. Then to orient the center properly, do the same as previously mentioned, but use the top and bottom edge instead of corners and have the center piece facing downwards instead of up.
5. Now orient the left and right edges downwards so they match the center
6. Final step, do the same as previously mentioned, but use the top and bottom edges to orient the middle left and right side

Comment: What about the name of the puzzle?